forecasting single step output using lstm
Does it make sense that I'm using LSTM where I'm taking inputs from the past 5minutes (0-5 mins), then I predict something 30s later, meaning at 5.5 minutes (5 min 30 sec). My data has a sampling freq of 5s, so I use a rolling window and move everything by 5s (just 1 step) in the next step and continue the data collection process and finally the prediction process.
Could you please suggest a tutorial which takes care of the data preprocessing?
Most of the tutorials on prediction I saw predicts just the immediate time step, in my case at 5 minutes 5sec, or if they are predicting a complete time series for few minutes (e.g., for 1 minute). But I want to predict single step after 30s
